# What's the point of the Dispatch skill?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

In Shadow of Mordor you can use the *Brand* skill to force Uruk to fight on your side.

There also is another skill you can unlock after *Brand* named ***Dispatch***:

> Dispatch:
>   Press [k] to kill all branded Uruks and monsters.

What's the point?

Not only are they not attacking you when branded, they also fight your enemies for you. Why would you ever want to kill them, let alone waste a skill point for this?

I am sure there is a reasonable case of application here that I am missing.

Comment: Sometimes my allies cause enemies to go to areas I don't want them to, like away from campfires. If you couldn't get rid of your allies this would be super annoying. I'm not setting this as an answer though since I have no idea if that's why the ability actually is in the game.

Comment: @atticae check out my answer if you haven't already. If you have you might want to consider accepting it to help others who might have a similar question :)

Comment: @Lokuzt I appreciate your answer, but there is no need to beg for an accept right after posting it. I get a notification of your answer anyway and many people (like myself) allow at least a day to wait for new answers coming in. That behavior might be counterproductive, just a friendly advice. :)

Comment: I saw a video on reddit the other day where some guy used dispatch to kill every single Captain, and the War Chief all at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well at first it doesn't make much sense to have that skill **BUT** there are applications.

For example if you want to use uruk captains to help you throw down a warchief but then you don't have much use for them, because outside of that fight they are just gonna wonder the map. They aren't gonna be at your side all the time. So you can brand them, kill warchief and then dispatch  them all.

I can think of rune farming maybe. I've seen many people do it. You brand an Uruk or Warchief, then you level up your branded uruks and then **BAM DISPATCH** you have yourself some runes.

These are applications I've seen and could think of for dispatch. Because I don't think Monolith would just let that skill go through if it didn't make sense in the game.

**EDIT:**

I just want to add that the skill only kills uruks near you. If you have a branded Warchief on the other side of the map it won't kill him!

**EDIT 2:**

There seems to be missions and achievements that Require Dispatch or Dispatch is useful in.

one example the [No Power in Numbers Achievement/Trophy](http://www.trueachievements.com/a188989/no-power-in-numbers-achievement.htm) where the dispatch is really useful to complete it.

And the [Sword Legend Missions](http://www.gosunoob.com/shadow-of-mordor/sword-legends-missions-guide/) in the mission: **Power of the One** ->

This mission has **Special Requirements: Combat Drain and Dispatch Abilities Unlocked!**

and **Main Objective: Make 10 Uruks kill each other by branding them, Eliminate all Branded Uruks**.

An image as reference:

[image]

So as you can see the dispatch is useful in bringing all of the down with style and quickly.

Comment: Hm, you usually never have more than one or two Warchiefs or Captains with you at the same time, so I am not sure why you would need an extra skill for that. You can just easily grab them and select "kill". But maybe they just ran out of skill ideas and did this one for the stylez ;)

Comment: Well that may be true sometimes but Warchiefs sometimes have more than 1 bodyguard. and lets say you level his bodyguards and then you take the warchief out. But man you want more runes (or better ones) so you can dispatch them to get them. I mean I honestly think it serves as a quick dispatch because killing uruks one by one if you have many can be tiring. :D

Comment: Hm well, this would still be a very rare scenario. (Do regularly use this skill?) Stands a bit out compared to all the other skills which you can/have to regularly apply in the game. But unless someone comes up with another use case, there probably isn't more to it than that.

Comment: @atticae i'm updating my answer

Comment: Considering how easy it is to unlock enough skill points for the entire tree, why not have a skill like this? :)

Comment: @Lyrical is kind of right. It's not that hard to gain points so them having this skill is not really big deal. I like the skill tree actually. It's a game that I have a lot of fun with.

Answer (score 2):

Very late but just in case anyone still ever wants to know, it regains focus. That means arrow, slowing down time, shadow strikes etc. It also can provide a non-practical kind of enjoyment to the game. I like going into battle branding a few guys to help fight and then execute them when it's over. I never brand captains or warchiefs because I like the enjoyment of killing them but if I did, this would make it easier to kill them. So obviously a strategy could be to brand guys in a fight with combat brand (A+B on Xbox) and kill them to regain focus and pick of a few remaining guys with arrows. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason no one has mentioned yet it using it to frighten groups of Uruk.

If you have unlocked the tier 3 Wraith ability Wraith Blast (On the 360 it's apparently called Wraith Finisher) it makes it so when you press <kbd>K</kbd> (or otherwise drain or flurry kill an Uruk) their head explodes and nearby Uruk are stunned for a duration dependent on the current Hit Counter Number:

> the size and strength of the stun distance depends on the current Hit Counter (weak at 0x-14x, stronger at 15x-29x, and strongest at 30x hit counter and up).

-[Shadow of Mordor Wiki](http://shadowofmordor.wikia.com/wiki/Wraith_Stun)

Branding a large quantity of Uruk would seem to work as a multiplier to this effect since multiple heads are exploding at once; however, I don't know if the game handles them in such a way that the stun is redundant, stacks, etc. That would definitely take a lot of testing, but it certainly does stun Uruk when used.